# In the Three Doctors, wouldn't the doctor know what to do?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Three Doctors, wouldn't the doctor know what to do since he has the memories of the others because they are his past.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually unfamiliar with this story, but the events of the [10th Doctor's Children in Need special](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWzt7cmWImY) (where he met the 5th Doctor) the 10th Doctor meets the 5th and solves a huge problem (of his own creation) which would have blown a hole in time and space.

At the end of the special, it's revealed that he knew exactly what would happen and how to resolve it because he remembered it from his time as the 5th Doctor.  He simply did everything he remembered himself doing, and solved the problem.

If I'm not mistaken, in the 5 Doctors movie the Doctors all had their memory of the events wiped before being returned to their respective times.

Thus, my guess would be that one of these is the case in The Three Doctors - either their memories are erased at the end of the crossover, or the two later regenerations of the Doctor are simply doing what they remember their respective selves doing from when they were the previous versions.

According to the Wiki article (which is relatively sparse on details) the Time Lords restore the Doctor's knowledge of traveling in time and space at the culmination of this serial.  This implies that they had removed it (which, IIRC, they had) and could have similarly removed the memories of the serial from the 1st and 2nd Doctors before returning them.